# Use Jquery to italicize all list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

My assignment is:

> In jQuery, write a function that italicizes all list elements on the page when the client fires the function (say, from a hyperlink)

This is how I am approaching this question:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
    //here I am trying to change the text because str.italicize() method didn't work
    var name = $('#lis').val() + "way";
    $('li').text(name);
  })
});
```

```html
<li id="lis">Saujan</li>
<li>Uprety</li>
<li>Saujan</li>
<li>Uprety</li>
<li>Saujan</li>
<li>Uprety</li>
<br>
<div class="in">
  <li>Saujan</li>
  <li>Uprety</li>
  <li>Saujan</li>
  <li>Uprety</li>
```

But it does not make the list elements italic.

How can I go about making all of the list elements on the page italic?

Comment: We are not going to code it for you. What did you try?

Comment: Please, read this before posting : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why don't you yourself try once

Comment: If you're struggling with some coursework I'd suggest you speak to your tutor

Comment: This isn't a free code creation service. Post a real question, with tries and we will help you.

Comment: Well guys, I apologize for not following the netiquette of posting here. It's my second time asking a question, I forgot to post my code. I have edited hope I will find a path to my solution. I don't want anyone to code my answers for me, I just want to know how shall I approach this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no string method named `italicize`. While there is a `String.prototype.italics` method, it is non-standard and should not be used

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/italics

One possible implementation in jQuery is to use the `css` method and pass in `font-style` as the attribute.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("li").css({"font-style":"italic"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Mangos</li>
  <li>Pineapples</li>
</ul>

<button>Italicize Fruits</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was actually talking about
 
var result = str.italics();

this one.

Oh I see now, didn't think it that way.